# android : alternative to tabTextAppearance in java

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I know, we have a property for setting text appearance on [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#attr_android.support.design:tabTextAppearance):

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
```

Any alternative method in java for setting it programmatically ?

**PS:** I am not using custom view for Tab, but the default one.

Comment: from the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java) i can say, currently there is no way to do it programmatically. But i guess you can use `getChildAt()` property of `ViewGroup` which will return `view` and with that `view` you can set `TextAppearance`.

Comment: @RaviRupareliya yes I saw the code.. My bad.. :(

Comment: which style you have to change, I mean, Did you need to set text size, typeface, bold,etc

Comment: @VigneshSundar I want to set text size.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add style programmatically by using a `CustomView`, Set `TextView` into that `CustomView` and applying style on the TextView.

For example.

```
mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new OnTabSelectedListener());
int tabCount = mTabLayout.getTabCount();
for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(i);
    if (tab != null) {
        TextView tabTextView =
            (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_item, mTabLayout, false);
        tabTextView.setText(tab.getText());
        // First tab is the selected tab, so if i==0 then set Tabs_Selected style
        tabTextView.setTextAppearance(getAppContext(), i == 0 ? R.style.TextAppearance_Tabs_Selected
                                          : R.style.TextAppearance_Tabs);
        tab.setCustomView(tabTextView);
    }
}


class OnTabSelectedListener implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab selectedTab) {
        int tabCount = mTabLayout.getTabCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            View tabView = tab != null ? tab.getCustomView() : null;
            if (tabView instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) tabView).setTextAppearance(getAppContext(), selectedTab.equals(tab)
                                                           ? R.style.TextAppearance_Tabs_Selected
                                                           : R.style.TextAppearance_Tabs);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }
}
```

**tab_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tab_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="Tab 1" />
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Tabs" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Tabs.Selected">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the child views from TabLayout & get the TextView instance & set the values

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
for (int count = 0; count < tabsCount; count++) {
    ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(count);
    int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
    for (int childCount = 0; childCount < tabChildsCount; childCount++) {
         View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(childCount);
         if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
             ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTextSize(16.0);
         }
    }
}
```

You can use custom TabLayout if you have more than one tab layout & set whatever you want

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class CustomTabView extends TabLayout {

    private Typeface mTypeface;

    public CustomTabView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTabView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomTabView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setupWithViewPager(@Nullable ViewPager viewPager) {
        super.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        this.removeAllTabs();
        ViewGroup slidingTabStrip = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);
        PagerAdapter adapter = viewPager.getAdapter();
        for (int i = 0, count = adapter.getCount(); i < count; i++) {
            Tab tab = this.newTab();
            this.addTab(tab.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i)));
            AppCompatTextView view =
                    (AppCompatTextView) ((ViewGroup) slidingTabStrip.getChildAt(i)).getChildAt(1);
            view.setTextSize(16.0);
        }
    }
}
```